# How to I find documents which does not contain a word mentioned?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am new to MongoDB and am having a few issues with it. I am trying to delete all of the documents that don't contain the word "happy". I want to make use of the indexes to search the documents but I am getting a lot of errors.

I am using a collection named `article`.

```
cursor = db.article.find({ $text: { $search: { '$ne': 'happy' }}})

Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "\"$search\" had the wrong type. Expected string, found object",
    "code" : 14,
    "codeName" : "TypeMismatch"
}

cursor = db.article.find({ $text: { $search: { '$not': 'happy' }}})

Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "\"$search\" had the wrong type. Expected string, found object",
    "code" : 14,
    "codeName" : "TypeMismatch"
}
```

I also tried the one given below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
cursor = db.article.find( { $text: { $search: "-happy" } } )
```

How do I find it? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this `db.collection.find({
  collection: {
    $regex: "^((?!happy).)*$",
    $options: "i"
  }
})`?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: this works but it's very slow. I would like to make use of the index to search the documents.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to get all documents where `key` not exact `happy` you can use this query:

```
db.article.find({key: {$ne: "happy"}})
```

if you need to filter with like you can use this one

```
db.article.find({key: {$not: /happy/}})
```